# Help choosing the appropriate .NET CMS for a project

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, content-management-system, umbraco

I have been assigned to integrate a CMS to our .NET based website.
The CMS needs to ease the work load for our users.

They should be able to upload PDF files, categorize them, tag them, Write their name and it should be displayed in a TABLE on our website. I should be able to search by category and tag and name. Also should be able to Sort by date (on the tables I guess).

Can this be integrated inside of our website for just one page ??

I would like to use one good CMS that is not complicated and works with IIS 6.0 and is 'for dummies'.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Did any of the other questions on .NET CMSs on Stack Overflow not solve your problem? http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+.NET+CMS&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a17560d1ef61d5f5&biw=1920&bih=995

Comment: There is a wide variety of options in MS Web App Gallery http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx?category=ContentMgmt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check opensource ? Check Codeplex.com . Your requirement seems to be pretty easy and if you are not to be using any complex features rather than uploading a PDF file and displaying and searching than I would rather suggest implementing on your own.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebFileManager.aspx
http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=4572

If you want to do some more things than just file upload like creating custom HTML pages etc.
http://www.mojoportal.com/
http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/umbraco.aspx